# PermissionDenied: 403 error when trying to run async Google Cloud Speech async transcribe

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-speech

I'm getting the following error when trying to run an async transcription request on a .flac file hosted on google cloud.

```
$ python3 transcribe_async.py gs://[file].flac
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 54, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 514, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "[]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 448, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
    details = "The caller does not have permission"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1533912393.258761000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1095,"grpc_message":"The caller does not have permission","grpc_status":7}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transcribe_async.py", line 105, in <module>
    transcribe_gcs(args.path)
  File "transcribe_async.py", line 83, in transcribe_gcs
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
  File "[]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/speech_client.py", line 284, in long_running_recognize
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata)
  File "[]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 139, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 260, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "[]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 177, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "[]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 206, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 56, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission
```

I've added an export statement to my .zshrc file that points to the service account json, I've added myself, the service account email and the project owner and editor as owners of the cloud bucket through the browser, and I ran `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="[].json"`, but nothing helps. What have I forgotten? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your file [publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects). Once you set the permissions to allUsers, you will be able to use your file in your request.

Comment: @F10, what if you don't want to share your file publicly? In most applications, you want to protect your data, so you need to let the google speech-to-text API to authenticate first, for example, using a server key. The question is - how to do that?

Comment: You could give reader permission to the service account that you're using to do API requests without making it publicly readable

Comment: You could use the following gsutil command to give permission to the Service Account to read your file `gsutil acl ch -u <Your_Service_Account>:R gs://<Your_Bucket>/<Your_File>`